# Show Cordova-media-capture video feed in a html element?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I´m developing an application with Intel XDK and I can open the video-camera through cordova-media-capture but I need to open the video feed in a DIV.

I tried this tutorial: https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/06/05/cordova-sample-capture-and-display-video/

But still opens the video-camera in a different window

How can I achieve it? Can anybody give me other example?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

> Start the video recorder application and return information about
>   captured video clip files.

**Properties**

***limit:*** The maximum number of video clips the device's user can capture in a single capture operation. The value must be greater than or equal to 1 (defaults to 1).

**duration:** The maximum duration of a video clip, in seconds.

```
// capture callback
var captureSuccess = function(mediaFiles) {
    var i, path, len;
    for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
        // do something interesting with the file
    }
};

// capture error callback
var captureError = function(error) {
    navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'Capture Error');
};

// start video capture
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit:2});
```

Please visit official [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media-capture/#capturevideooptions) for better understanding.